# Apache Camel 3.20.0 SFTP Key Exchange not working

Tags: xml, apache-camel, public-key-exchange

The key exchange works perfectly when performing SFTP between my local servers. It also works correctly when I manually connect with SFTP @ - no password required. As soon as I go to a server outside my network, with the XML script the key exchange fails. I have sent my server's public keys and they have been installed in the authorized keys file. I need to know a parameter for the XML script to allow the key exchange to take place.

I have included the `serverHostKeys=ssh-dss,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,aes256-ctr and the publicKeyAcceptedAlgorithms=ssh-dss,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,aes256-ctr`. I was hoping this would solve the key exchange problem, but it hasn't. Here are some things from the

```
log:
Apache Camel 3.20.0
Java 11.0.21
Apache Tomcat 9.0.69
JSCH 0.2.1

    Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4unbuntu0.fips.0.9
    Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH_0.2.1
    CheckCiphers: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
    CheckKexes: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,curve448-sha512
    CheckSignatures: ssh-ed25519,ssh-ed448

SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received

kex: server: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
kex: server: rsa-sha2-512, rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
kex: server: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
kex: server: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
kex: server: hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
kex: server: hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com

kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 {ssh-rsa}
kex: server->client cipher: aes256-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-512 compression: none {aes128-ctr}
kex: client->server cipher: aes256-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-512 compression: none {aes128-ctr}
kex: ecdh-sha2-nistp256 need=64 dh_need=64
kex: ecdh-sha2-nistp256 need=64 dh_need=64
sent packet: type 31
```

Comment: The certificate is a private key not a public key.  Public keys are used for each connection and the are developed from the private key.  Is the certificate signed?  You may have a certificate that is not signed and remote servers require a signed certificate while local server may not require a signed certificate.  What OS are the remote servers?  SFTP uses TLS and two things could be failing 1) Older operating systems may not support the encryption mode in the certificate 2) The version of TLS !1.2 or 1.3) may not be compatible with the certificate.  Best to allow both 1.2 and 1.3 to work.